# Can a PS4 banned from online play download system updates?

Tags: ps4

I'm looking at buying a used PS4 for playing offline games from disc. The best deals by far are on systems that have been banned from playing online so I was wondering if that would affect me? The only thing that comes to mind is system updates - can a banned PS4 still download them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can still download system updates for a banned PS4

> You can see what's new in the "What's New" section, browse the online manual, use the Internet browser, **download new system updates**, and use Remote Play using wireless LAN.
>   
> <sub>(emphasis my own)</sub>

[Source](https://support.playstation.com/s/article/Information-on-Banned-Accounts-and-Consoles)

Comment: Many thanks! You answered my question and it was the answer I wanted to hear :-)